# Encrypting data in url

Tags: php, encryption

l have some data in json format e.g `{"utm_source":"","utm_medium":"","utm_campaign":"","utm_term":"","utm_content":""}` and l want to send them encrypted as uri to another domain (`example.com/$encrypted_data`) and then decrypt them. How can l do that (with PHP) so the encrypted string contains only those chars: [A-Z, a-z, 0-9, -, /] and decryption is possible using the specific key? I am using PHP 8.1

Comment: I think you're confusing encryption with encoding... I guess you're looking for something like `base64_encode()`, though this is not an encryption

Comment: @HonkderHase no l am looking for encryption base64 can be decoded by anyone. I want the data to be available only for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  
// Store a string into the variable which
// need to be Encrypted
$simple_string = "Welcome to GeeksforGeeks\n";
  
// Display the original string
echo "Original String: " . $simple_string;
  
// Store the cipher method
$ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";
  
// Use OpenSSl Encryption method
$iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
$options = 0;
  
// Non-NULL Initialization Vector for encryption
$encryption_iv = '1234567891011121';
  
// Store the encryption key
$encryption_key = "GeeksforGeeks";
  
// Use openssl_encrypt() function to encrypt the data
$encryption = openssl_encrypt($simple_string, $ciphering,
            $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);
  
// Display the encrypted string
echo "Encrypted String: " . $encryption . "\n";
  
// Non-NULL Initialization Vector for decryption
$decryption_iv = '1234567891011121';
  
// Store the decryption key
$decryption_key = "GeeksforGeeks";
  
// Use openssl_decrypt() function to decrypt the data
$decryption=openssl_decrypt ($encryption, $ciphering, 
        $decryption_key, $options, $decryption_iv);
  
// Display the decrypted string
echo "Decrypted String: " . $decryption;
  
?>
```

output

```
Original String: Welcome to GeeksforGeeks
Encrypted String: hwB1K5NkfcIzkLTWQeQfHLNg5FlyX3PNUA==
Decrypted String: Welcome to GeeksforGeeks
```

You can use openssl_decrypt() for decrypting data in PHP. you can read more about openssl_decrypt(); to know more how handle decrypt and encrypt string

Comment: I've seen this method, but the encrypted string contains "=" character.

Comment: @Kyansittha: It's probably base64-_encoded_ ... but please mind the difference of encryption vs. encoding!

Comment: @HonkderHase its not base64. Base64 does not require specific key to decode. I want to ENCRYPT the data so it can be accessed only by me. P.S. l missed comma between "encryption" and "base64" in the latest comment